# How can I 'open in terminal' when using Ubuntu subsystem on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As the question states, I'm using Ubuntu on Windows 10. Every time I have to work on a homework problem and have to open Ubuntu, I have to navigate to the file path which is tedious.

Is there any way to right-click on the file explorer and hit **open in the terminal**, like in a real Ubuntu operating system environment?

Comment: Search: [windows 10 open directory in bash](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows%2010%20open%20directory%20in%20bash) -> StackOverflow: [Windows 10 Open Directory in Bash Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178346/windows-10-open-directory-in-bash-ubuntu) -> HowToGeek: [How to Quickly Launch a Bash Shell From Windows 10’s File Explorer](https://www.howtogeek.com/270810/how-to-quickly-launch-a-bash-shell-from-windows-10s-file-explorer/) -> type `bash` in explorer window's address bar to open `bash` at that location.

Comment: @SHawarden Can you please expand that and post as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

This option is available within the Windows 10's extended context menu. You can achieve this menu by holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and click with the <kbd>right mouse button</kbd>, somewhere in the empty space in the File explorer.

There are few [other approaches](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167821/how-can-i-open-in-terminal-when-using-ubuntu-subsystem-on-windows-10/1168337#comment1947974_1167821), but for my this is pretty enough.